# Box API Stating Users Max Upload Size is 0

Tags: box-api

I'm getting the following response from the /about/me request to the API for user I'm trying to access through the API.

It states that the user's max upload size is 0, even though his space amount is listed as 1073741824000, which seems to suggest he's probably on a [business](https://www.box.com/pricing/) plan.

How am I supposed to behave based on this value?  Does this mean the user is not allowed to upload files, or perhaps that they have no limit?

```
{
    "type": "user",
    "id": "<redacted>",
    "name": "<redacted>",
    "login": "<redacted>",
    "created_at": "2012-01-31T18:16:08-08:00",
    "modified_at": "2013-02-04T17:41:51-08:00",
    "language": "en",
    "space_amount": 1073741824000,
    "space_used": 178518128089,
    "max_upload_size": 0,
    "status": "active",
    "job_title": "",
    "phone": "<redacted>",
    "address": "",
    "avatar_url": "<redacted>"
}
```

EDIT: Changed the example to show the raw JSON to remove any questions about the parsing misinterpreting the value.

Comment: this is a potential bug–we're looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for spotting this.   The zero was an artifact of a new way of calculating the max size of file we'll allow the user to upload.   We're calculating this on the fly, so any new users in the last few weeks would have this field be empty.

Fix for this should be out in the next few days.